# Capture or Export konvajs stage with the layer position

Tags: javascript, konvajs, konvajs-reactjs

I have 2 layers on my KonvaJs Stage. 
The layer on front or the topmost contains shape (ie. circle or rect).
The layer on the back is an image with 3200x3200 dimension (This will act as the background image).
My stage is only 1024x1024. Now I had my layer on the back (which is the image) draggable. This will give me freedom to position the image the way I wanted it.

However, whenever I export the stage as PNG, it does not include the layer final position. The export does work with all the layers and shapes. But the layer on the back which is the background image was exported as how it was positioned initially. NOT the final position after moving `onDragEnd`. Below is my straightforward script to get the image data.

```
   const dataURL = stage.current.toDataURL({
    quality: 1,
    pixelRatio: 2,
  });
```

Does any body knows how to properly export the stage with updated positioning of the layers?

Any response is greatly appreciated.

Best regards,

Comment: Can you make a demo? From the description, you should have such behavior.

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time. I kinda solve it the other way but I will make a sample so everyone that might have different solution can put it here too.

Comment: Sorry, I have a typo. You should NOT have such behavior. What was your solution?